# In aws-auth configMap, what is the difference between username and groups in mapRoles, respectively mapUsers

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-authorizer

I am working to assign AWS IAM Roles to AWS EKS RBAC Roles/Cluster Roles. I am checking this document "Enabling IAM principal access to your cluster" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html .

 At the documentation link above there is this example of a `aws-auth` configMap.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/my-role
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/my-console-viewer-role
      username: my-console-viewer-role
  mapUsers: |
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      userarn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/admin
      username: admin
    - groups:
      - eks-console-dashboard-restricted-access-group      
      userarn: arn:aws:iam::444455556666:user/my-user
      username: my-user
```

My questions would be:

 1. In aws-auth configMap, what is the difference between `mapRoles`:`username` and `mapUsers`: `username`? Same question for `mapRoles`:`groups` and `mapUsers`: `groups` ? Is it mandatory to have both `username` and `groups` arguments in the `mapRoles` or in the `mapUsers`?

2. In this sample of `aws-auth` configmap:

```
mapRoles:  
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::11223344:role/Developer                                                                                                      
  username: Developer                                                                                                                                       
  groups:                                                                                                                                              
  - eks-cluster-read-only-group                                                                                                                            
  - eks-developer-group
```

How to translate the `username` and `groups` in this case from K8S perspective? So I am logging with the AWS IAM Role named Developer. Does this mean I get the RBAC permissions assigned to both the K8S username `Developer` and (&&) the K8S groups `eks-cluster-read-only-group` and `eks-developer-group` ? And in order to see these permissions I should look in K8S/EKS for the RBAC roles and cluster-roles which have as `subject` the username `Developer` and/or the groups `eks-cluster-read-only-group` and `eks-developer-group`? Like `kubectl describe clusterrole eks-readonly-cluster-role` ? Then I can know which permissions does the IAM Role `Developer` have?

Thank you.